# Change linetype for the group of timeseries in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 4 time series with different types. Right now I would like to plot all of them and distinguish type '0' and type '1' with dotted or solid line.
My code:

```
data1<-data.frame(year<-seq(1990,by=1, length.out=50),values<-rnorm(50,0,1),Stage="A", Type="0")
data2<-data.frame(year<-seq(1990,by=1, length.out=50),values<-rnorm(50,0,1),Stage="B", Type="1")
data3<-data.frame(year<-seq(1990,by=1, length.out=50),values<-rnorm(50,0,1),Stage="C", Type="0")
data4<-data.frame(year<-seq(1990,by=1, length.out=50),values<-rnorm(50,0,1),Stage="D", Type="1")

data_combined<-rbind(data1,data2,data3,data4)
colnames(data_combined)[1:2]<-c("year","values")

ggplot(data=data_combined, aes(x=year, y=values, group=Stage))+
  geom_line(aes(linetype=Type, colour=Stage), size=1)
```

I am not sure how to change to the opposite linetype - I want type '0' to be dotted and '1' to be the solid line.

[image: Sample Plot]

Comment: Suggest defining the data like this: `set.seed(123);
n <- 50;
Data <- data.frame(year = seq(1990, length = n), values = rnorm(4 * n),  Stage = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), each = n), Type = rep(c("0", "1", "0", "1"), each = n))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest next modification in your code. The function `scale_linetype_manual()` from `ggplot2` allows to modify the linetype as you want:

```
library(tidyverse)

#Data
data1<-data.frame(year<-seq(1990,by=1, length.out=50),values<-rnorm(50,0,1),Stage="A", Type="0")
data2<-data.frame(year<-seq(1990,by=1, length.out=50),values<-rnorm(50,0,1),Stage="B", Type="1")
data3<-data.frame(year<-seq(1990,by=1, length.out=50),values<-rnorm(50,0,1),Stage="C", Type="0")
data4<-data.frame(year<-seq(1990,by=1, length.out=50),values<-rnorm(50,0,1),Stage="D", Type="1")

data_combined<-rbind(data1,data2,data3,data4)
colnames(data_combined)[1:2]<-c("year","values")

#Plot
ggplot(data=data_combined, aes(x=year, y=values, group=Stage,linetype=Type))+
  geom_line(aes(colour=Stage), size=1)+
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c('1'='solid','0'='dotted'))
```

Output:

[image]